# store authenticated user data in session in mvc4 web services and use it furher

Tags: web-services

I'm working on web services in mvc4.In which i need to authenticate user and give access of particular web service.For that after login, saved access token in session. But i'm able to access that session data in same web services, but can't in another web services.While i want to access it in my whole web service project.How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the client is setting up different sessions between each call to the webservices.

I think a better approach for you would be to write a persistent authentication cookie to the client and check on each succinct call. Cookies are automatically sent on each request by the client.

Ps. Sessions are tracked by session cookies, just like above, only they are not persistent so the session cookie is deleted as soon as the client closes the connection.